# How to add an item to list inner hashmap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

```
HashMap<String, List<Person.Personal>> hashMap = new HashMap();

var attachment = new Person.Personal(name, surname, birthDate);
```

I need to add item with key that comes from another map.

Then I need the code like below;

```
if(hashMap.containsKey(courseGroup.getKey().get(0)))
{
    hashMap.put(courseGroup.getKey().get(0), attachment);
}
else
{
    hashMap.put(courseGroup.getKey().get(0), new Arraylist<Person.Personal> (attachment));
}
```

This code show error:
Cannot resolve constructor 'Arraylist(Person.Personal)'

If the hashmap has the key then add its value list "attachment", if has not, create a list then add "attachment", I need.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Look into the method ```getOrDefault``` of ```Map```

Comment: is `attachment` a `POJO` or an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Question edited:This code show error:
Cannot resolve constructor 'Arraylist(Person.Personal)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(hashMap.containsKey(courseGroup.getKey().get(0)))
{
    hashMap.get(courseGroup.getKey().get(0)).add(attachment);
}
else
{
    List<Person.Personal> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(attachment);
    hashMap.put(courseGroup.getKey().get(0), list);
}
```

These lines solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

As the arraylist already exists instead of putting it again use updating the arraylist.

For example:

```
if(hashMap.containsKey(courseGroup.getKey().get(0)))
{
    // adding values directly to the arraylist.
    hashMap.get(courseGroup.getKey().get(0)).add(attachment);
}
else
{

    List<Person.Personal> list= new Arraylist<> ();
    list.add(attachment);

    // create a new array and put it there.
    hashMap.put(courseGroup.getKey().get(0), list);
}
```